# ¿Porque no se lleva a cabo la conversión bien?

Tags: string, dev-c++, double

buenas tardes, tengo un problema con este código, lo que hace el código es abrir un fichero .csv para leer el contenido de este y, como esta delimitado por comas hay una función que detecta donde esta la coma y guarda los números en forma de string por separado sin la coma para luego en teoría transformarlo en un valor double.
El problema esta en que cuando le pido que haga la conversión, no la hace bien y da un número aleatorio en lugar del string convertido a double, para la conversión utilizo el comando atof().
Adjunto el código para que puedan verlo.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdlib>
double tiempo[]={}, voltaje[]={};
int i=0, X=0, L=0;//X detecta donde esta la coma y L detecta la posición del último char del string
char nombre_csv[]={};
char delimitador=',';//Caracter a ignorar al analizar el csv
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
using namespace std;
int fit_exp();//aqui se lleva a cabo la lectura
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(){
    cout<<"introduce el nombre del csv (con el .csv/cualquier otra extension incluido)"<<endl;
    cin>>nombre_csv;
    fit_exp();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
int fit_exp(){
 ifstream  datos;//Se indica que se va a abrir un csv
 string variables, tiempos, voltajes;
 datos.open(nombre_csv,ios::in);//Abrimos el archivo csv y con el ios::in lo declaramos como lectura
 if(datos.fail()){
    cout<<"no se pudo abrir, el archivo puede que no exista o no este ubicado en la carpeta del programa"<<endl;
                }
 else{
    cout<<"Se abrio correctamente"<<endl;
//Guardar datos
    while(!datos.eof())//recorrera 1.csv hasta el final
        {
            getline(datos, variables);
            cout<<"nueva iteracion: "<<i<<endl;
            //cout<<variables<<endl;
            L=variables.length();//Saca la longitd total de caracteres del string 'variables'
            X=variables.find(delimitador);
            tiempos=variables.substr(0,X);//Sacara en formato string el tiempo
            voltajes=variables.substr(X+1,L);//Sacará en formato string el voltaje
            cout<<"el valor de X: "<<X<<endl;
            cout<<"el valor de X+1:"<<X+1<<endl;
            cout<<"string tiempos da: "<<tiempos<<endl;
            cout<<"string voltajes da:"<<voltajes<<endl;
            tiempo[i]=atof(tiempos.c_str());            ///////////el atof falla al convertir//////////////////////////////////////
            //voltaje[i]=atof(voltajes.c_str());
            i++;
            cout<<"vector de tiempo da: "<<tiempo[i]<<endl;
            //cout<<"El vector de voltajes da: "<<voltajes[i]<<endl;
         }
    }
    datos.close();//Termina la lectura del csv
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ¿ Porque no se lleva a cabo la conversión bien ?

Te equivocas. La conversión se está llevando a cabo **perfectamente**.

Lo que estás haciendo mal es **guardar** el resultado de la conversión:

```
double tiempo[ ] = { }
...
tiempo[i] = atof( tiempos.c_str( ) );
```

En C++, un *array* no se auto-redimensiona. Se define con un tamaño, y con ese tamaño se queda hasta el fin de sus dias. Por lo tanto, tu estás accediendo a posiciones en un *array* de tamaño 0 ... y eso es un *comportamiento indefinido*. El resultado está totalmente indeterminado ... que es lo que te está pasando a tí.

Para no meternos en historias de memoria dinámica y otras *yerbas*, una posible solución es usar un [`std::vector< >`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) que, esta vez si, se encargará el solito de aumentar su tamaño de ser necesario:

```
#include <vector>

...

vector< double > tiempo;

...

tiempo.push_back( atof( tiempos.c_str( ) );
i++;
cout << "vector de tiempo da: " << tiempo.back( ) << endl;
```